# How to retrieve data from SQL Server from XML file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <ProductID>
    <Producer value="SomeName" />
    <Locality value="California" />
    <Chamber value="ATK-01B" />
    <System value="CAL-ATK-01B-01" />
  </ProductID>     
</Data>
```

The above is the XML file gets saved in the column `content` of a SQL Server table. I am using the below query to select the records from DB with value `CAL-ATK-01B-01`.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table name] 
WHERE [xmlBody].value('(/Data/ProductID/System)[1]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE 'CAL-ATK-01B-01';
```

I need to select all records with matching value in xml file as `"CAL-ATK-01B-01"`. But the query I tried is returning empty value.

Can any one help me do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this query here to actually select the value of the XML **attribute** `value`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table Name]
WHERE [xmlBody].value('(/Data/ProductID/System/@value)[1]', 'varchar(100)') LIKE 'CAL-ATK-01B-01';
```